# Deploying manually a CircleCI build to Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, circleci

I am new to CircleCI and would like to know how **to deploy manually a CircleCI build to Pivotal Cloud Foundry**.

Say my CircleCI build passes (tests, ect.) and is therefore "known to be good" and I want to deploy that to Cloud Foundry.

Is there a way to deploy that CircleCI build manually instead of continuously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define [build artifacts](https://circleci.com/docs/build-artifacts/) in CircleCI, which you can just download after the build passes and `cf push` them from your machine.

Anyways, I would rather suggest to continuously [deploy from a certain branch](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#deployment), e.g. `staging` or `production`. You may then trigger the builds by merging into that branch. To get started, have a look at the [CircleCI documentation for Bluemix/PWS](https://circleci.com/docs/deploy-bluemix/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving you an example of circle.yml

```
machine:
  java:
    version: oraclejdk8
dependencies:
  pre:
    - curl -v -L -o cf-cli_amd64.deb 'https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=debian64&source=github'
    - sudo dpkg -i cf-cli_amd64.deb
    - cf -v
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - cf api https://api.run.pivotal.io
      - cf auth $CF_USER $CF_PASSWORD
      - cf target -o [org] -s [space]
      - cf push [app-name]
```